# Java 8: Why Effectively Final variable doesn't work for switch block?

Tags: java, function, java-8, switch-statement

Why Effectively Final variable works for functions and not  for switch block ?

The following example gives a compilation error

```
    String comparing = " ";
    String effectivelyFinal = "Hello ";
    switch(comparing){
        case effectivelyFinal :
            System.out.println("Are equal");
            break ;
        default :
            System.out.println("Are not equal");
    }
    Predicate<String> areEqual = s -> s.equals(effectivelyFinal);
```

Comment: Because switch is to compare constant, not against others variable...

Comment: @Walfrat in Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final. So why switch can't see  effectively variables ?

Comment: It has to be known at compile time...And I don't understand why you're using a `switch-case` here...instead of a simple `if-else`

Comment: The point of an effectively final variable is to guarantee the variable's value won't change. It does not, however, control how its value is determined. Its value can be resolved at runtime. A `switch` statement can only work with values that are constant, known at compile time.

Comment: @AKSW I am preparing the java 8 oracle certification, and I got this question, I answered that there are no compilation error because I thought that the variable effectivelyFinal is considered as final but my response was wrong :( that's why I asked this question

Comment: As already said. *compile time* vs. *runtime*. Good luck with the exams.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't think so because " Why can't I switch on a String"  is not related to java8

Comment: @Aguid You haven't got a single relevant answer, because you shouldn't ask questions beginning with 'why' on stackoverflow. You could make a try with more theoretical stackexchange sites. But to answer your question, it's just a design decision. Of course, contrary to repliers' claim, effectively final property of a variable is a compile time term.

Answer (score 3):

The code doesn't compile simply because *only constant expressions* can be compared against when using a switch case. whereas with lambdas (anonymous functions) , we are not restricted to this extent.

just to clarify any more confusions, *effectively final* simply means a variable or a parameter whose value is *never* changed after it is initialized but doesn't necessarily make it a *constant expression* as you can change it; in which case it's no longer *effectively final* hence why it's disallowed as a switch case expression.

Answer (score 2):

A switch label must be one of three types, as per [Section 14.11 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

```
SwitchLabel:
    case ConstantExpression : 
    case EnumConstantName : 
    default :
```

By [Section 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConstantExpression), a constant expression can be, among other things,

> Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

Your simple name does not refer to a constant variable, and so is not allowed.

For lambdas, on the other hand, the JLS makes no such restriction.

Comment: Interestingly, it was `Expression` in earlier versions. Seems they have changed that.

Comment: What version, out of interest?  I've gone all the way back to Version 3 and it still says `ConstantExpression`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html  Look for "SwitchLabel" as in your example

Comment: That's strange, because Section 14 of the same spec says ConstantExpression: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html

Comment: Certainly it was required to be constant before, independent of the name in the grammar.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: the name in the grammar is indeed irrelevant, as the grammar only tells the parser how a class file is structured, but at this level, you can’t tell expressions and constant expressions apart. See the OP’s example. At the `case` label, a parser can’t tell whether the referenced variable is a constant or not.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `effectivelyFinal` is not really a `final` as you can reassign it to any other string.

Compiler is assured about `compile-time constants` and not effectively constants.

More on this in Java Language Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

If you update your code by adding `final` keyword to the variable then it would become a `compile-time constant` and code would compile as now `effectivelyFinal` variable is really a `final` as you cannot change its value anymore.

```
String comparing = " ";
final String effectivelyFinal = "Hello ";
switch(comparing){
    case effectivelyFinal :
        System.out.println("Are equal");
        break ;
    default :
        System.out.println("Are not equal");
}
Predicate<String> areEqual = s -> s.equals(effectivelyFinal);
```

For lambda or regular functions, there is no such restriction.